# How can I keep same layout for large screen and tablet for my app?

Tags: html, css, layout, media-queries

I am developing an audio/video app. I want to keep the same layout for desktop and tablet. But I don't want to use responsive Technic.

Is there any way to fit desktop app to fit in tablet(something like zoom out and fit).

Comment: Question is way too broad. Provide (code) examples please.

Comment: You'll want to pick an aspect ratio, and then scale based on viewport units like `vh`, `vw`, `vmin`, and `vmax`.